# RXJS webSocket Subject onconnected

Tags: websocket, rxjs

I need a Observable to subscribe to when my Rx.Obervable.webSocket is connected. There is an openObserver property I can use but I don't how to create a Observalbe out of it.

```
const WebSocket = require('ws');
const Rx = require('rxjs');

const observer = {
  next: (event) => {
    console.log('Test');
  }
}

const socket = Rx.Observable.webSocket({
  url: 'ws://192.168.100.155:2001',
  WebSocketCtor: WebSocket,
  openObserver: observer,
  protocol: 'server'
});

isConnected().subscribe(() => {
  // do something after socket is connected ...
});
```

Comment: what is `isConnected()`? I guess you wanted to write `socket.subscribe()`.

Comment: sry that wasn't clear. I need a Observable where i can subscribe to, when the socket is fully connected. isConnected() should be the function returning such an Observable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you could do something like this:

```
const subject = new Subject();

const socket = Rx.Observable.webSocket({
  url: 'ws://192.168.100.155:2001',
  WebSocketCtor: WebSocket,
  openObserver: subject,
  protocol: 'server'
}).multicast(subject);

subject.subscribe(...);
```

This should first emit a value to the subject when the connection is established and then emit every single message.